# Redirect Router with React after an HandleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help with redirection after validation of the Log-in form in fact 
I query a database by the API on http: // localhost: 5000 / api / v1 / users / login by making an Email and Password post and it returns a Token which I put in my globalState users: 
I'm sure security level etc ... it's not great but I'm trying to learn React + API Server and authentication.
And suddenly in my code I do this:

```
export default function SignIn() {
    const { addUser,error, users } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const classes = useStyles();
    let emailInput
    let passwordInput
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(emailInput)
        console.log(passwordInput)
        const newUser = {
          email: emailInput,
          password: passwordInput
        }
        console.log(newUser)
        addUser(newUser)
        if(users!=[]){
          return <Redirect to={"/"}/>
        }
      }
```

And I would like that if my token is in the user table I will be redirected to the home
Thank you.

Comment: you wanna pass data with your redirect?

Comment: no i just want to go on Home Page(component) 
in fact I arrive on the log-in page and after i want go on HomePage

Comment: Just returning `<Redirect>` component and not rendering it will not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the object notation in Redirect

If you want to pass some data to a route or redirect you can do it like this

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/",
    state: { user: newUser }
  }}
/>
```

This will pass the user data to the page you are traversing to and will put it in the props.

Comment: I do thank you but i don't change of page Redirect component comes from `import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";` ?